# Same volume for multiple containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

Currently I am working on a task that needs to create 4-5 different `docker containers`. Now the catch is that all these containers should be using the **same volume** mounted inside the container.

I am building the images using individual `Dockerfile`s and then running the containers using these images. The preferable way is to use `VOLUME` in `Dockerfile`s. But I am not sure how exactly to use it.

Here's a code snippet of a `Dockerfile` -

```
FROM [imagename]

WORKDIR \app

VOLUME \app\[container's folder]  #this folder is separate for each container. eg. VOLUME \app\sql

COPY shell.sh \app\[container's folder]\shell.sh

.
.
rest of code
```

After running the containers and bashing into it, for a particular container the files are getting stored inside the particular path; *eg. as in above snippet, `shell.sh` is present inside path `\app\[container's name]`*

But when I check in another container, I am able to see that container's files in the particular path, but cant see the first container's files.

This is how I want the structure -

```
app
|- sql
|   |- shell-script files
|- tsdb
|   |- shell-script files
|- kernel
|   |- shell-script files
.
.

OR

/app/sql/shellsql.sh
/app/tsdb/shelltsdb.sh
/app/kernel/shellkernel.sh
```

Comment: check `docker volume create` the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

Answer (score 1):

Assumming you have the following volumes for the containers

```
VOLUME /app/container1
```

---

```
VOLUME /app/container2
```

---

```
VOLUME /app/container3
```

The way share the volumes is as such. Create 3 volumes from command line:

docker volume create vol1 
docker volume create vol2
docker volume create vol3

When running each container, mount the all the volumes

```
docker run -v vol1:/app/container1 -v vol2:/app/container2 -v vol3:/app/container3 <image1>
docker run -v vol1:/app/container1 -v vol2:/app/container2 -v vol3:/app/container3 <image2>
...
```

Comment: So I have 4 containers to create each having volume /app/vol1, /app/vol2, /app/vol3 and /app/vol4 where /app is the common volume. So I'll have to create these 4 volumes from command line. Now when running `docker run` for each container will I have to mount each 4 volumes using -v option in each command?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using docker-compose?

docker-compose is the better way to run all containers in one command (you can run specific container also. In docker-compose, you can create configuration easily (mount volume, link containers to each other, network ... etc).

Please have a look at sample docker-compose file

```
container1:
 build: image_name
 volumes_from:
  - data_volume

container2:
 build: vra_manager2
 volumes_from:
  - data_volume
```

With above example, both containers are used the same data_volume. You don't have to write big command for each container.

For example:

```
volumes:
 - /vol1:/app/container1  
volumes_from:
  - data_volume
```

Comment: Okay so in `volumes_from` I'll have to write the common volume _(i.e /app in my case)_ or the entire volume that would be used i.e /app/sql, /app/tsdb, etc. Because the requirement is as such - there'll be a single volume used across all containers and that volume would be having sub folders used by each container individually.

Comment: I have updated answer, you need to use volumes and volumes_from flag

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try. Thanks.